# prependTo() inside load() completion callback not trigger when using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Why `prependTo()` inside `load()` completion callback not trigger when using `setTimeout()`? It just only repeat `load() result.php` but not execute `$('#loadmore').prependTo('#boxchat');`. Basically, i used this following code:

```
function requestmessage() {
    $('#boxchat').load('result.php', function(){
        $('#loadmore').prependTo('#boxchat'); 
    });
    setTimeout(requestmessage, 1000);
};
requestmessage();
```

I want to make real time `result.php` update by using `setTimeout()` and `prependTo() div(#loadmore)` inside `div(#boxchat)` at the same time. Anyone does have solution?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `.load()`. It will replace the content of `$('#boxchat')` with the content received from result.php on each completion. Instead of load, can you try using `.ajax()`, `.get()` or `.post()` (depending on your use case, `.get()` should work) and in the success / complete callback, give the call to `prependTo()`

Comment: Like this? $.get("result.php", function(data) {} but how target "result.php" into div "#boxchat". Don't tell me using prepend in "result.php" into div"#boxchat" too. I don't want using prepend with result.php.

Comment: save `let loadMore = $('#loadmore').html()` to a variable and use `$('#boxchat').html(loadMore  + data);`
It would be helpful if you could provide more context of the actual requirement.

Answer (score -1):

Check your browser console. Maybe load() call encountered some exception (/error) that halted the execution of the script, so it did not even reach prependTo() call.

If you are using Google Chrome - that would be Ctrl + Alt + J.

Comment: I was checking, but nothing error show in Google Chrome console inspect. The console is empty. In this situation when first load, div is showing but after setTimeout() repeat them then the div is disappear.